# Google Auth The requested action is invalid

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform

So I'm using the firebase authentication with google sign in, svelte-kit, and when ever I try to sign in, it either immediately closes, or a couple of times has a popup with `The requested action is invalid.`

I'm using Stack Blitz, and the auth appears to go through `{proj}.firebase.app` What's Causing the issue?

code

```js
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth();
function signin(){
            signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then((result) => {
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
                const token = credential.accessToken;
                const user = result.user;
            }).catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                const email = error.customData.email;
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
            });
        }
```

click btn

`<button type="button" on:click={signin}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem!

1. In Firebase, while looking at Firestore, open the Build accordion and tap on Authentication.
2. Once you've selected Authentication in the left hand gutter, select the "Settings" tab from the middle of the page.
3. On the Authentication/Settings screen, look down until you see "Domains" and then "Authorized Domains".
4. Tap "Authorized Domains" and the screen will change a bit. Click Add Domain and then copy the URL you stack blitz project is using into that field (get rid of the https:// scheme so you just have the URL).
5. Save and give it 30 seconds or so and then try again.

That seemed to work for me.

--- OLD

I was experiencing this exact problem. The key here is "I'm using Stack Blitz".

The problem went away when I download the Stack Blitz project and ran it locally. My guess - the problem is related to some of the magic that Stack Blitz has to do. Something Stack Blitz is doing doesn't play nice with the protection built into Google Auth. Maybe something related to the requesting domain, etc.

There *might* be a way to update some settings in Firebase to allow this request from Stack Blitz but I was coming up short after a bit of googling.

Comment: yeah future projects tended to work from a local machine, I'm guessing the routing is whack due to the weird way stackblitz works?